# Why are there 40 commandments in 10 commandments?

Tags: aseres-hadibros

When do one commandments stop and the next one start? Who's counting? Who got the number 10?

1. I am Hashem
2. your God
3. You shalt have no other gods before me
4. You shalt not make any graven image (So no 3D printing?)
5. You shall not bow down to them
6. or serve (them)
7. You shalt not take the name of the Lord thy God in vain
8. Remember the sabbath day
9. to keep it holy
10. Six days you shall labor
11. And do all your work
12. but the seventh day is a Sabbath to the LORD your God.
13. On it you shall not do any work, you
14. or your son
15. or your daughter
16. or your male servant
17. or your female servant,
18. or your ox
19. or your donkey
20. or any of your livestock,
21. or the sojourner (non jews?) who is within your gates,
22. that your male servant
23. and your female servant may rest as well as you.
24. You shall remember that you were a slave in the land of Egypt,
25. and the LORD your God brought you out from there
26. with a mighty hand
27. and an outstretched arm.
28. Honor thy father
29. and thy mother (2 commandments)
30. Thou shalt not kill (actually murder/certain types of killing presumably against other humans only. Many killing, is perfectly fine and encouraged. Just read http://biblehub.com/1_samuel/15-3.htm)
31. Thou shalt not commit adultery (Most disagree on what it really means)
32. Thou shalt not steal
33. Thou shalt not bear false witness against thy neighbor (literally comrades)
34. You shall not covet your neighbor's house
35. you shall not covet your neighbor's wife,
36. or his male servant,
37. or his female servant,
38. or his ox,
39. or his donkey,
40. or anything that is your neighbor's.

Some may think my division to 40 is excessive. Still if I shorten it, it'll still be way more than 10. Most denominations divide the commandments differently anyway, suggesting that the division is not clear cut.

Comment: [Devarim 4:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0504.htm#13) but it never says there are only 10 commandments. More like 10 statements.

Comment: It seems you are asking two different questions and might consider splitting it into two separate threads: 1. About how to divide the ten commandments 2. Why is the last commandment seemingly addressed only to men

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I mean c'mon.... This one is not even politically incorrect.

Comment: 10 words in mechon mamre. So is God talking about these 40 commandment or some other sentences with 10 words?

Comment: Command 24 is interesting. So, how things went in Egypt? Did you remember it? Got pics, memento, etc.?

Comment: 10 statements? There are far more than 10 statements there.

Answer (score 12):

That which you call the 10 commandments are in Hebrew referred to as the Aseres HaDibros, which means the 10 utterances or 10 statements.  There is no implication that there are 10 commandments therein.  I think your 40 is a bit excessive (as you conceded), but the classic counts list either 13 (Behag) or 14 (Rambam) commandments in these 10 statements.

As an example that they are not one commandment each, it is actually the opinion of several major authorities (Behag, Ramban Hasaga 1 to Sefer HaMitzvos) that the first statement is not a commandment at all.

Comment: Some christian denomination count the first as a whole commandment. The second one is there should be no other God. Some combine 1st and 2nd into 1 commandment. I wonder where number 10 comes from. Everyone says it's 10 commandment. Rabam, as you said, think there are 13 of them.

Comment: @JimThio the bible itself refers to asseret hadvarim. Asseret=10. Dvarim=statements (or maybe "things").

Comment: where in the bible it says asseret dvarim?

Comment: @user4951 Exodus 34:28

Answer (score 1):

**"The Ten Commandments**" or *Decalogue* is not a Biblical concept - and you won't find a reference to it in the Tanach.

So your question makes an assumption - based on a popular mistranslation!

The closest you will get is a Pasuk in Devarim 10:4

> וַיִּכְתֹּב עַל-הַלֻּחֹת כַּמִּכְתָּב הָרִאשׁוֹן, **אֵת עֲשֶׂרֶת הַדְּבָרִים**, אֲשֶׁר דִּבֶּר ה' אֲלֵיכֶם בָּהָר מִתּוֹךְ הָאֵשׁ, בְּיוֹם הַקָּהָל; וַיִּתְּנֵם ה', אֵלָי

Which roughly translates [with my comments] to:
"And He [Hashem] wrote on the [second] tablets as was written in the first, the **10 items** that Gcd spoke to you on the mountain [of Sinai] from within the fire on the day of the gathering and Hashem gave them [the tablets] to me."

How to get to 10 is a matter of dispute - and you can see 7 various versions from various schools of thought on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Commandments#Traditions_for_numbering).

See the answer from YEZ [above](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37603/501) for some Jewish opinions.

Regarding your query as to who decides what is a Mitzva - that has rules, as discussed in the Talmud. A popular set is [Rabbi Yishmael's 13 principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraita_of_Rabbi_Ishmael) we say in Shacharit every morning. Or see *[Rules by which early Jewish law was derived](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halakha#Rules_by_which_early_Jewish_law_was_derived)*.

Comment: 10 items. Does that refer to the 10 (actually 40 commandments) or other 10 items or 10 other things?

Comment: @JimThio - The verse refers to the 10 (actually ±40) commandments.

Comment: How many tablets do God uses anyway for that 10 items? Christians believe there are 2 tablets. The first 4 items are in the first one and the second ones on the last. Then there is another that says that there are 2 tablets, each are "carbon copy" of another.

Comment: @JimThio - it's says explicitly in the Bible that there were 2 stone tablets given to Moses. What was written on them is open to debate.

Comment: @DannySchoemann He asked in comment if the verse refers to 10 commandments or items. And you replied to him in comment saying commandments, that's clearly wrong. As you know, mitzvot are commandments. dvarim is not commandments, it's statements. Your answer translates it fine but then your comment doesn't.

Comment: what is dvarim? The ten commandments? I mean saying things like, "thou shall not kill" looks like commandments to me than "statements">